# How we can create two column layout and assign partial page using sitecore sxa?

Tags: sxa

*[image: emphasized text]*

Right side part, i.e. *partial page4* -  its a reusable for many pages.
In left side part -- we can add no of partial page.

How can we achieve this structure using Sitecore SXA?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly here is how I would do it:

1. Create a partial design
2. Put **Column Splitter** rendering into `main` placehodler

[image]

3. Then put **Row Spltter** rendering into left column (in my case `column-1-1`)

[image]

4. Then you can assign your partial design to a page design and use it, here is how it will look like when you open a page. Nobody is allowed to move those placeholders on pages.

[image]

Your common layout can be shared across multiple pages = profit ;)

I added colors to visually show how the page layout will be divided thanks to column and row splitters.

### Docs

- [Page designs](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/page-designs.html)
- [Create and change a partial design](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-and-change-a-partial-design.html)
- [Create and assign a page design in the Content Editor](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-and-assign-a-page-design-in-the-content-editor.html)

Comment: Hi Alan,  I think you understood is different. If we create  all components in single partial design means it will work,  In my scenario I have different partial pages, if I integrate that all partial pages in single page design , I have to show that format.  Is it possible?  Is there any other solution

Comment: I don't understand why you need to have several partials. Read about `Snippet` rendering (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/configure-a-snippet.html). I think it might help you a little. This is a rendering but works like partial.
Alternatively you could try *Base Partial Design* (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-and-change-a-partial-design.html#idm45493639748384_body)