# Placeholder setting for partial designs

Tags: sxa, presentation

I was creating a page similar to the image below with SXA 1.7.1 in Sitecore 9.0.2

In my situation, I have the 'translation section', 'Videos' and 'The Weeknd' to be reusable.
Search results can be there, cannot be there and will vary in length.
[image]

**What I did**:
So, I created 2 partial renderings:
 Partial Rendering 1: Contains 'translation section' and 'Videos'
 Partial Rendering 2: Contains 'The Weeknd'

Both my partial renderings are on placeholder 'main'.

I added both the partial designs to the page design and published the site.

**What happened**:
'The Weeknd' section got displayed below 'Videos'

**What I could have done**:

I would have taken a column splitter on the page and would have designed the partial templates accordingly. (I am yet to try this.)

**The challenge**:

1. Is there a way to add the rendering for 'Search Results' between the sections 'Videos' and 'The Weeknd'?
2. Is there a way to use to select separate placeholders for each
   partial rendering on different page rendering?

I am asking this question as I am feeling that reusability of 'partial design' is getting curtailed in the present scenario.
Any suggestion will be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer yourself a question what grid system you are going to use.

SXA can use: Bootstrap3, Bootstrap4, Foundation, Grid960.

Once you select yours learn how to build a layout with it.

I would do it this way.

1. Create **MainBase** partial design
2. Edit **MainBase**

   - add **Column Splitter** rendering to `main` placeholder with 2 columns
   - set widths of two columns to **8**, **4**
3. Create **MainLEFT**
4. Edit **MainLEFT**

   - set `Base Partial Design` field value to **MainBase**
   - open your partial
   - drop **Translation** rendering to left column (this with width 8)
   - drop **Search** rendering to left column (this with width 8)
5. Create **MainRIGHT**
6. Edit **MainRIGHT**

   - set `Base Partial Design` field value to **MainBase**
   - drop **Video** rendering to right column (this with width 4)

It should look more or less like this

[image]

Technically you don't have to create **MainBase** and then use it as a base. You could treat **MainBase** as your main partial and put all renderings that I listed above on a single partial. I felt that you need something advanced to switch them later feel free to go with an easier approach if needed (add partial, drop column splitter, set widths, drop translation, drop searach, drop video).

Building layout like that is not that hard, I created something on the same level of complexity for **[XA.Reference](https://github.com/alan-null/XA.Reference/releases)** demo site: **[screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alan-null/XA.Reference.Wraith/master/shots_base/movies/MULTI_casperjs_pattern.png)**. You could install this site and see how I combined all partials to designs there.

I hope it helps. I cannot understand your second question.

#### You might want to read [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/15359/16) answer, I feel it is related.